# .htaccess Query String Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have been going round in circles for a few hours, would really appreciate a little help.

I am trying to rewrite URLs that include a query string (preceded by company.php).

I found a few ways to get the rewrite itself to work, but it always shows a 404 :(

For example I need to rewrite (using example value):

```
http://test.domain.com/company.php?companynumber=05614768
```

to:

```
http://test.domain.com/company/05614768/
```

Here is a couple I have managed to get to do the rewrite but are 404ing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/company\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companynumber=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.domain.com/company/%1/? [R,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companynumber=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^company\.php$ http://test.domain.com/company/%1/? [R,L]
```

I am guessing I need to figure out how do an internal redirect as well as the external redirect? But I am really struggling...

Centos 6.6 / Apache 2.4.12

Comment: @mario - If I understand, yes I think so. I am trying to get it to do an internal redirect as well as the external redirect (which I think is working). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now if that's your old-to-new redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companynumber=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^company\.php$ http://test.domain.com/company/%1/? [R,L]
```

Then remap the new incoming URL via:

```
RewriteRule ^company/(\d+)/?$ company.php?companynumber=$1 [END]
```

Note that this:

- Must be a rule *thereafter*.
- Should carry the `[END]` flag to avoid another internal rewrite round.
- Only allows numeric `\d+` placeholders.

See also "Ping-Pong rewrites" on [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and “pretty links” explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108/345031). These rewrites should just be used as temporary measure. Establish the new URLs right in your HTML templates.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mario! I will try and use the above now and report back. Much appreciated.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! You have done in 2 minutes what would have taken me weeks. Thanks again!